# Find asp.net controls during a loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In a asp.net vb code are several panels with ids like pnl_TN1, pnl_TN2, pnl_TN3, ..., pnl_TNx.
The panels are all visible = false .

How can I iterate from i =2 to 4 with setting pnl_TNi visible to true?

Comment: <!-- tn2 -->
                <asp:Panel ID="pnl_TN2" runat="server" Visible="false">...</panel>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FindControl`:

```
For i As Integer = 2 To 4
    Dim ctrl = Me.FindControl("pnl_TN" & i)
    If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
        ctrl.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach. Maybe error occurs cause it is in a masterpage <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

Comment: thanks, at least there is no error. but the panels 2,3 and 4 are still unvisible...

Comment: Dim mpContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
        mpContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"), ContentPlaceHolder)


        For i As Integer = 2 To 4
            'Dim ctrl As Panel = Page.Master.FindControl("pnl_TN" & i)
            Dim ctrl As Panel = CType(mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("pnl_TN" & i & ""), Panel)

            If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
                ctrl.Visible = True
            End If
        Next